# CSS/HTML column height issue

Tags: html, css

Can anybody take a look at the website I designed http://www.ensorbuilding.com - in Google Chrome.

The middle column almost always overlaps the left and right.

I am using the jquery auto heigh which should set the height of the left,middle and right columns automatically but it doesn't seem to be doing it correctly!

Any thoughts?

Thanks :)
Dan

Comment: I'm using chrome 15 and the only problem I see is with the content and the footer when making the window smaller. Did you mean that?

Comment: Under latest blog posts in the middle column. The posts overlap the footer when the window is expanded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding some margins to the `<aside>`s and the `<section id="content">` elements.